# Need backup program capable of copying delta/incremental file changes only

Tags: windows, backup

I'm looking for a good reliable Windows program that I can use for backing up to a networked hd.  I need it to be able to copy only the delta bits (changed bits) of files instead of copying the entire file.  I already know about Not DeltaCopy and Areca Backup, I've tried both and am still looking.

(Also, not wanting an internet solution)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future searchers, the two I found were [Super Flexible File Synchronizer](http://www.superflexible.com/) and [Altaro Oops Backup](http://www.altaro.com/).  SFFS has a lot of options and looks good, but is really intended for syncing rather than making archival backups.  I went with Oops.  It is strictly a file backup software but is really good at it (even will put backup files in a secondary location if desired) and simple to use.  Neither are free, but I was willing to pay a little bit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Acronis Driveimage

Comment: Can you point me to any of Acronis's documentation where it says their software will backup deltas of files to a networked hd?  I can't find it on their website.

Comment: @CChriss - Download the user guide for Acronis True Image Home 2011 and look at section *3.6 Using Acronis Nonstop Backup*.  It mentions: *"You may think that at these backup rates the storage will fill in no time. Do not worry as Acronis True Image Home 2011 will back up only so called "deltas". This does not mean that entire changed files will be backed up, but only differences between old and new versions."*

Comment: Thanks for the info firedfly.  Unfortunately, according to the page I saw, it is in beta, which is not for me.

Comment: I think you meant Acronis True Image or Backup and Recovery.  Powerquest made Drive Image, years ago, but then Symantec swallowed them up.

Comment: @CChriss: True Image has always been able to do what you want, and the more high-end versions (and the new Backup and Recovery) can also consolidate incremental backups after a specified amount of changes, which saves a lot of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

[CrashPlan](http://b3.crashplan.com/consumer/features.html) backups up incremental changes to any connected drive. the free version is likely adequate for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I heard [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) can run on Windows, but it can be quite a challenge to make it work.